# The "general" question tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have a tag called [general](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general). Why do we have this tag? Shall we burn this tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Yes.  With the fire of a thousand suns.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general)